# What to do with this "wasted" space in my side bar navigation mockup?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, desktop-application, breadcrumbs, sidebar

I am currently working on a new UI design for an existing desktop application.  Being mobile/touch friendly is very important for this project, so I am replacing the tradition desktop "File" menu with a touch friendly side bar design.  So far, this is what I have:

[image]

The side bar allows you to navigate between various workflows in the application.  The breadcrumb trail at the top shows where you are in your selected workflow, and allows you to quickly navigate to any previous step.

My question is, what should I do with the area where the side bar, and the breadcrumb trail intersect?  I currently just have the word "Menu" there referring to the side bar.  However, I can't help but feel that I am wasting space here.  Is there a better way I can combine a side bar with a breadcrumb trail so I don't waste space where they intersect?

Comment: Couldn't you simply remove the "Menu" field and move "File" up?

Comment: I thought about that but then it wouldn't align well with the breadcrumb bar.  Maybe that isn't a big deal?  I could always make the breadcrumb bar taller so that its the same size as the side bar boxes.  But I thought that would be too big.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Logo / Brand name
- Remove "Menu" and make the breadcrumb smaller, so it doesn't suggest some relation with "File"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need the space at all.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Your app's icon or company logo.**

Clicking it should take the user to screen the "Home" link does.

Using your icon or logo will re-enforce your brand and appear natural to the user.

Comment: In this case "Home" is relative to which ever work flow is selected from the side bar.  The application doesn't really have a traditional "Home" screen.

Comment: The link location being relative would be preferred, however having it non-clickable would also be acceptable.